# Trying to bidirectionally reference two cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, reference, cell

I'm basically wondering why the following Google Scripts' script won't work bidirectionally.
If I edit NW!P2, then History!R2 correctly updates, while if I edit History!R2, NW!P2 doesn't care.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e.source) {
    console.error("Error: e.source is undefined");
    return;
  }

  var nwSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('NW'); // Set the name of the NW sheet
  var historySheet = e.source.getSheetByName('History'); // Set the name of the History sheet

  var range = e.range;
  var value = range.getValue();
  var sheetName = nwSheet.getName();

  // Update History!R2 when NW!P2 is edited
  if (range.getA1Notation() == 'P2' && sheetName == 'NW') {
    historySheet.getRange('R2').setValue(value);
  }

  // Update NW!P2 when History!R2 is edited
  if (range.getA1Notation() == 'R2' && sheetName == 'History') {
    nwSheet.getRange('P2').setValue(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showing script, `var sheetName = nwSheet.getName();` is always the sheet name of `NW` from `var nwSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('NW');`. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue, if you want to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var sheetName = nwSheet.getName();
```

#### To:

```
var sheetName = range.getSheet().getName();
```

or

```
var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
```

- By this modification, `sheetName` is used as the sheet of the edited cell.

Comment: I am so dumb.. I think I just need a break. Your code obviously solves my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: @lucottoDA About `Your code obviously solves my issue. Thank you so much!`, Welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "NW" && e.range.columnStart == 16 && e.range.rowStart == 2 ) {
    e.source.getSheetByName("History").getRange("R2").setValue(e.value);
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "History" && e.range.columnStart == 18 && e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    e.source.getSheetByName("NW").getRange("P2").setValue(e.value)
  }
}
```